# MSB4019: missing Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets whilst running MSBuild via TeamCity in VS2017 Build Tools

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, teamcity, visual-studio-2017

I am getting the following error when trying to build a WCF dependent project in VS2017:

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WCF\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets"
>   was not found.

I have installed MS Build Tools 2017, but this does not include WCF. Does anyone know where I can find the correct installer for WCF with MSBuild2017?

Comment: It's looking for the 2010 targets... Even when you install the full 2017 enterprise these files won't come with that. You may need to upgrade your projects or install the 2010 build tools/visual studio.

Comment: You can just copy the targets to given location oh the build machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with errors: `The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WCF\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets" was not found.`

To fix it,

1. I had to install MSBuild from the link given below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-using-msbuild?view=vs-2019

which got installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools` location.

2. Then I had copied `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WCF"` folder to the `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\"` location, as requested in the error message.
3. Then tried to reload the project, which worked fine.